# Python mechanize module proxy setting question

Tags: python, mechanize

It seems like these codes would work:

```
MechBrowser = mechanize.Browser()
MechBrowser.set_proxies({"http": "111.11.11.11"})
response = MechBrowser.open("http://google.com")
```

But as you see "111.11.11.11" is just a random ip I came up with to test if the proxy setting works, and it's not a valid proxy. The weird thing is MechBrowser still open google.com without giving any error, so does this mean if the proxy you set not working mechanize will use default setting to browse? If I want it to throw exception when the proxy is broken, how should I do?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax is ok, and its working on my machine as it should do.

```
------> print(mechanize.__version__)
(0, 2, 1, None, None)

>python -V
Python 2.6.5
```

When proxy is unavailable, for example, it will raise URLError. I can recommend you to check the version of mechanize+python you`re using at the moment and run this code in python interpreter interactively.

Comment: My mechanize version is: (0, 2, 2, None, None), I don't really know what the numbers mean though. And my python version is 2.7. Obviously "111.11.11.11" is not a valid proxy, and the interpreter still raises NO URLError when opening google.com through this proxy, so I really don't know what went wrong...

Comment: I found what the problem is, the port number is NOT optional as said at http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/ ! In my interpreter, only when you use proxies like "111.11.11.11:8000" it will raise URLError, or mechanize browser will open pages using default settings!

Comment: # Note the userinfo ("joe:password@") and port number (":3128") are optional.  — right from http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/. SO, the proxy is valid and it works for me. Type 'ping 111.11.11.11' in you shell(win or linux, doesn`t matter) and watch the output - just for sure. Just tried 0.2.2 version — everything is ok. So, update your mechanize to 0.2.4, try to run this script via python 2.6 and try to run it on another computer.